# jquery IE8 - using live('blur', function) and live('change',function) together

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, onchange, blur

Ok, I have a weird problem with IE8 and jQuery.  See the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<input>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.tools.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input').live('blur',function(){alert('blur');});
        $('input').live('change',function(){alert('change');});
});
</script>
</html>
```

With the code as is, I can't get the on change event handler to fire after editing the input field.  However, if I comment out the blur event handler, then on change will fire.

Why does IE8 do this?  What should I do to make both on blur and on change work simultaneously across all browsers?

Comment: It's a nasty hack, but hvae you tried triggering them both via a delay of 0 seconds?

Comment: please....nooooooooooooo....do I really have too??? there's got to be something better...

Comment: I dunno if you really have to, but that delay hack has helped me out plenty in IE8 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html) includes the older v1.4.2 of jQuery. This seems to have a bug in IE8 that breaks your intended functionality. Upgrading to [v1.6.1](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js), then both events fire in IE8. I tested the older versions of jQuery and whatever was broken was fixed in v1.4.3 so if you cannot do a major version upgrade for whatever reason, then hopefully a minor version upgrade will be OK.